# Защита: результаты авторизации

Tags: защита

Заметил, что на многих сайтах, если во время входа я ввёл неверные данные, то он пишет сообщение "Неверный логин ИЛИ пароль". Лично мне так неудобно - аккаунтов много на разных сайтах - попробуй вспомни какой у тебя логин именно на этом. Поэтому, было бы удобнее уточнять ЧТО ИМЕННО введено неправильно. Т.е. писать "Неверный логин", если такого пользователя вообще нет и "Неверный пароль", если такой пользователь есть, но пароль введён неверно. Что я у себя на сайте и сделал.

Собственно вопрос: целесообразно ли такое делать - уточнять ошибку? (раз даже гугл пишет "Неверный логин ИЛИ пароль"). Потому что, с одной стороны, это удобнее, а с другой - взломщику упрощается работа: даже случайно угадав логин, он может уже пробовать ломать пароль, иначе ещё бы и логин думал бы как "хакнуть".

**UPD:** Всё же стоит ли пожертвовать такого рода защитой ради такой функциональности? Вроде не очень то и потеря большая (уточнение ошибки), но нынче пользователи чересчур привередливы.

Answer (score 6):

Если Вам важна безопасность Ваших пользователей - я бы не советовал это делать.

**Мой ответ: так делать нецелесообразно**

Comment: Это нецелесообразно только в случае, если логин скрывается сайтом.  
То есть `nickname != login` и при этом логин пользователя не светится на страницах.  
Если ник и логин это одно и то же, то имеет смысл указать конкретную ошибку, потому что угрозы безопасности это не создаст ни в коей мере.

Comment: @ReinRaus, преобразуйте свой коммет в ответ.

Comment: +1 за ответ, добавить собственно и нечего.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а кто будет следить за пользователями, чтобы они Все вводили nickname!=login? или, даже, пусть введен верный login, но при этом указывать что все дело лишь в пароле.

Comment: @w2 есть много сайтов, где логин и ник это одно и то же. Чаще всего это форумы, даже у ХэшКод это так.  
Если пользователь ошибся на одну букву в логине, то очень много шансов, что такого логина просто не существует и указать это не излишне.

Comment: @ReinRaus дело в защите от перебора. Допустим на гуглмейле существует условие: пользователь всегда должен получить доступ к почте. Если кто-то начинает перебирать login на предмет наличия, то он, не проходя процедуру авторизации может узнать список зарегистрированных пользователей при вводя даже неверный пароль, но он будет видеть - логин существует или нет. Заблокировать такой перебор для почтового сервиса можно лишь по ip, но эта блокировка обходится добавлением нового прокси сервера из списка. Задача может быть такой, что нельзя блокировать доступ к учетной записи на сайте. В этом все дело

Comment: @vv2 я написал в первом комментарии под этим вопросом при каких условиях имеет смысл давать точную ошибку.  
Представьте, что на сайте есть страницы с анкетами пользователей с адресом вида  

    site.ru/user/vasja
    site.ru/user/petja
    или
    site.ru/user/id100500
    site.ru/user/id123
Не вижу никакой разницы как брутфорсом получить имена пользователей: перебирая логин в адресе или в форме авторизации.